# Why does my MacBook Pro screen flicker after about 20 minutes?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

I am using 13-inch MacBook Pro (2017), Two Thunderbolt 3 ports.

After use of ~20 minutes my MacBook Pro screen starts flickering I don't know what is the issue however it works with external monitor.

I tried below methods but none worked:

1. Reset SMC.
2. Reset NVRAM.
3. Cooling pad.
4. Updating latest OS.

Could it be a hardware issue?

Answer (score 2):

You have failing display. It’s likely a component that is related to the power of the display (LEDs) itself. If I were to take a [SWAG](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_wild-ass_guess) at it, I’d say there are failing [capacitors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor) at play here.  [Capacitors can be used to smooth out voltages](https://electrotopic.com/how-does-a-filtering-capacitor-smooth-a-changing-current) There’s obviously enough power to “light up the display” but the image just isn’t smooth the way it should be.  Given that the issue presents after 20 minutes, it’s probably a heat related issue.

Your Mac needs to go in for service.